# What's wrong with the syntax ON UPDATE CONVERT_TZ?

Tags: mysql

Unable to create an ON UPDATE action when creating a table for the CONVERT_TZ function

What's wrong with the ON UPDATE CONVERT_TZ syntax, why is the same for DEFAULT or ON UPDATE NOW()? I need to force the "updated_at" column to be updated without triggers, taking into account the time zone.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'UTC','Europe/London')) ON UPDATE (CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'UTC','Europe/London'))
)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can specify anything other than `current_timestamp` or a constant as the default or on update value.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible:

The syntax for ON UPDATE is defined in [sqlyacc.yy](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L7487):

```
ON_SYM UPDATE_SYM now:
```

now is defined as NOW_SYM, so according to [lex.h](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/lex.h) only the following symbols are supported:

- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- NOW()
- LOCALTIME
- LOCALTIMESTAMP.